# Value factor from Ken French's library

Tags: fama-french, factor-investing

I'm after returns of the Value factor (book-to-market) from [Ken French's library](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html). Based on the description, I'm guessing it's this one: `Portfolios Formed on Book-to-Market`. The [csv](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/Portfolios_Formed_on_BE-ME_CSV.zip) has the following headings:

- SMALL LoBM
- ME1 BM2
- SMALL HiBM
- BIG LoBM
- ME2 BM2
- BIG HiBM

I'm guessing Small/Big relates to the large/small market cap halves and Lo/Hi relates to low/high B/M. What does `ME1 BM2` and `ME2 BM2` mean? Is Value factor return calculated as `((BIG HiBM - BIG LoBM) + (SMALL HiBM - SMALL LoBM)) / 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the value factor, you want to download the "Fama-French 3 Factors" or "Fama-French 5 Factors" product. Those have the excess returns (i.e. return in excess of the risk free rate) for HML, their value factor. Their construction is described in the [details page](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/f-f_5_factors_2x3.html). For further details, read their papers.

As described in the links above, you can replicate their calculation of HML using portfolio returns of their [six portfolios sorted on size and book to market](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/six_portfolios.html). Reconstructing HML yourself may enhance understanding of what HML is and how it is constructed, but you can just download the HML time-series from the [data library](https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html).